# next and prev button for a custom pager using PagedDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the next and prev button on my custom pager. Here is what I have so far and it's working perfect except it needs next and prev button.

**What I have done**

```
 PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();

                page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
                page.AllowPaging = true;
                page.DataSource = query;
                page.PageSize = 5;
                QRep.DataSource = page;
                QRep.DataBind();
```

*Qrep is a asp.net repeater control and *query is a result of linq to sql query.

**here is how i create the pager controls and assigned event handlers**

```
private void CreatePagingControl()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (RowCount / 5) + 1; i++)
        {


            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_Click);
            lnk.ID = "lnkPage" + (i + 1).ToString();
            lnk.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            plcPaging.Controls.Add(lnk);
            Label spacer = new Label();
            spacer.Text = "&nbsp;";
            plcPaging.Controls.Add(spacer);

        }

    }

    void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
        int take = currentPage * 5;
        int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 5;
        FetchData(take, skip);
    }
```

the row count is stored as below

```
private int RowCount
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)ViewState["RowCount"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["RowCount"] = value;
        }
    }
```

This is working fine , except it only displays page numbers and I want to know how the next and prev controls can be integrated with this. Any help appreicated guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the open source pager control for asp.net 3.5 here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNETPagerControl.aspx

**Edit**

There is also another asp.net pager control with source code here:
http://aspnetpager.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks , but I am looking for something i can use with linq to sql datasource.

Comment: From http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNETPagerControl.aspx, "the ASP.NET 3.5 project has a sample to show how to utilize LINQ as Pager control's data provider."

Comment: If you want to use aspnetpager.codeplex.com, just replace the ado.net queries from the sample code to use your linq queries.

Comment: I downloaded that project file but the reference dll is not found. gives me an error ,"ASPnetControls.PagerV2_8' is not defined"